# How to use block from module on CMS page?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template, cms

I have a block class called `Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Block_Form`.

```
<?php
class Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Block_Form extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    private $n2g;
    private $session;
    private $customer;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( !isset($this->n2g) ) {
            $this->n2g = Mage::Helper("fekete_newsletter2go");
        }
        if ( !isset($this->session) ) {
            $this->session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        }
        if ( !isset($this->customer) ) {
            $this->customer = $this->session->getCustomer();
        }
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->customer->getEmail();
    }
}
```

This is the config entry:

```
<global>
  ...
    <blocks>
        <fekete_newsletter2go>
            <class>Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Block</class>
        </fekete_newsletter2go>
    </blocks>
```

How can I use it on a CMS page?

I tried it like this:

```
{{block type="fekete_newsletter2go/form" template="fekete/Newsletter2Go/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

But then nothing is rendered, it only works with `core/template`.

Comment: Can you post your block class file here?

Comment: ok, I posted it.

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you clear your cache and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add your block type to the allowed blocks under `System > Permissions > Blocks`.

One of the recent M1 SUPEE patches added this feature for security reasons, requiring blocks included in CMS content to be white-listed.

Comment: Nice hint! Thanks. Im not sure why you get a downvote, it is not from me.

Comment: Yes, This is perfect answer for this question, I think `SUPEE-7405` added this feature   https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code . I have just replace code Newsletter2Go To newsletter2Go.

```
{{block type="fekete_newsletter2go/form" template="fekete/newsletter2Go/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: The template is not the problem...